# What is the cause of Resin saying `@Named('dpa') is a duplicate name for ...` when there is no such value?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, resin

I have an existing Java EE 7 webprofile web application working on TomEE and Glassfish.  I have now tried to deploy it on Resin 4.0.55 Open Source edition.  My mechanism to have CDI inject configuration strings using `@Named("key") String` fails with:

```
/home/tra/Hentet/resin-4.0.55/conf/app-default.xml:55: @Named('dpa') is
a duplicate name for
  ProducesMethodBean[String, IngesterModule.provideDestinationPath(), {@javax.inject.Named(value=dpa.putfile.destinationpath), @Default(), @Any()}, name=dpa.putfile.destinationpath]
  ProducesMethodBean[String, IngesterModule.provideDeliveriesFolder(), {@javax.inject.Named(value=dpa.deliveries.folder), @Default(), @Any()}, name=dpa.deliveries.folder]
```

There is no `@Named("dpa")` in my source, but the names listed in the error message have keys starting with dpa.

What does this mean?  What is the cause? and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message "`@Named('{0}') is a duplicate name for\n  {1}\n  {2}`" is found inside the `InjectManager.java` class file.

Relevant source code:

```
  private void addBeanByName(String name, Bean<?> bean)
  {
...
    // ioc/0g31
    int p = name.indexOf('.');
    if (p > 0) {
      addBeanByName(name.substring(0, p), bean);
    }
  }
```

The given name is splitted using the period character (`'.'`) as separator, and the given bean is added to the context for each part recursively. This behaviour must be described in the CDI 1.0 (JSR-299) or maybe the implementation is buggy.

The `ioc/0g31` comment looks like a reference to an issue, but I couldn't find it in the [bug tracking system](http://bugs.caucho.com/view_all_bug_page.php).

Comment: I asked at the Resin group and the bug is reported fixed in 4.0.56 https://groups.google.com/d/msg/caucho-resin/gnrBliY-Z0Y/2f57c-V8BQAJ